# An interesting way of communication between two activities

Tags: java, android, android-handler

The first step:

```
public class MyHandler extends Application {
    private Handler handler = null;

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

}
```

The next step:
In activity A:

```
MyHandler myHandler = (MyHandler)getApplication();
    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(msg.what == 0x123)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    myHandler.setHandler(handler);
```

In activity B:

```
MyHandler myHandler = (MyHandler)getApplication();
Handler handler = myHandler.getHandler();
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x123);
```

Although the reference of two myHandler is same, we use (MyHandler) to change Application to MyHandler.The Application has no field of handler,why can the Application keep the filed handler? Because I think in activity B, `MyHandler myHandler = (MyHandler)getApplication();` can't obtain the filed handler.

Comment: Why you don't use the onActivityResult mechanism?

Comment: Do you have `<application android:name=".MyHandler" ...>` in your manifest ?

Comment: Yes,I  have <application android:name=".MyHandler" ...> in your manifest ,but my question is why can the Application keep the filed handler?

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism.

The *reference* being of type `Application` doesn't necessarily mean that the *referenced object* is. The object could be `Application` or any subclass of `Application`.

Writing `(MyHandler)` before a value is a *cast*, and simply converts the *reference*, not the *object*. The validity of the cast is checked at runtime, and a `ClassCastException` will be thrown if the object is not `MyHandler` or a subclass thereof (in your case, the check passes, so it's no problem).

Comment: The Application has no field of handler,why can the Application keep the filed handler? MyHandler in activity B is not the same as it in activity A,I think,Because Application don't have handler field.

Comment: Read up on polymorphism (inheritance/subclassing) and references in Java.

Comment: I think you mean to convert subclass to  super class,but  when I convert the super class to subclass, I think they should have the same reference,and the super class can't use fields which only belong to his subclass.

Comment: You're not changing the actual object, just the type of the *reference*.